# Deployment Error. Server Error. connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have just created two basic functions in my index.js but on deploying through command prompt I am facing this deployment error server error connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.196.202:443

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const original = req.query.text;
  const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original});
  console.log(snapshot.ref.toString());
  res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
});

exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const original = snapshot.val();
      console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
    });
```

I am not able to figure out why am I getting this error. I was not getting this error before but after I added console.log() in addMessage() I started getting this error.

Comment: check internet connection and still the error occurs do `firebase logout && firebase login && firebase deploy`

Comment: I actually did that twice. But an interesting thing was when I ran the command `firebase deploy` for 5 to 6 times it failed and after that executed perfectly.

Comment: yes dont do it so frequent. sometimes the APIs dont respond as they have designed them in such a way so that no one can not abouse them. when you deploy too frequenltly they stop responding and you get that error